# What encoding am I looking at

Tags: php, encoding, joomla3.0

A plugin in my Joomla installation stores the following data structure/encoding in the database:

> `a:20:{s:3:"UID";s:32:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";s:11:"X-EXTRAINFO";s:0:"";s:8:"LOCATION";s:0:"";s:11:"allDayEvent";s:3:"off";s:7:"CONTACT";s:0:"";s:11:"DESCRIPTION";s:63:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";s:12:"publish_down";s:9:"2015-9-23";s:10:"publish_up";s:9:"2015-9-23";s:13:"publish_down2";s:9:"2015-9-23";s:11:"publish_up2";s:9:"2015-9-23";s:7:"SUMMARY";s:17:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";s:3:"URL";s:0:"";s:11:"X-CREATEDBY";i:708;s:7:"DTSTART";i:1443031200;s:5:"DTEND";i:1443045599;s:5:"RRULE";a:4:{s:4:"FREQ";s:4:"none";s:5:"COUNT";i:1;s:8:"INTERVAL";s:1:"1";s:5:"BYDAY";s:24:"+1SA,+2SA,+3SA,+4SA,+5SA";}s:8:"MULTIDAY";s:1:"1";s:9:"NOENDTIME";s:1:"1";s:7:"X-COLOR";s:0:"";s:9:"LOCKEVENT";s:1:"0";}`

I replaced some characters with x's to erase 'sensitive' information.

I get how the encoding works: it uses arrays(a), string(s) and integer(i) with some length, if applicable, between colons.

However, I want to know name of this encoding and I would like to know it there is some off-the-shelf php-function that parses the information, like json_decode for JSON.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding appears to be ['a storable representation of a value'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

As @AbraCadaver states in the comments, the PHP function `serialize` converts PHP data objects to this representation. The PHP function `unserialize` creates a PHP value from the stored representation.